# Ignoring .DS_store preferences clientside

Tags: macos, finder, file-server, .ds-store

At work our largely shared fileserver is filled with .DS_store preferences from various users. We clean these files now and then, but still it happens constantly that I run into a folder where someone has opened folders in the list view, or has changed the view to column view, and these settings have been saved in the .DS_store file and are directly applied to my folder view.

Is there a way where I can tell OSX to ignore all .DS_store view preferences when browsing through specific folders?

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to try persuade it not to write them in the first place...

1. Open Terminal.
2. Execute this command: 
   `defaults write com.apple.desktopservices DSDontWriteNetworkStores true`
3. Either restart the computer or log out and back in to the user account.

From [Mac OS X v10.4 and later: How to prevent .DS_Store file creation over network connections](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht1629) which apparently has never been superseded or indeed maintained for a long time, but is still the recommended way.

You might also find this interesting - [Got a Mac? Prevent OPSEC leakage by cleaning hidden OS X files from USB drives](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2834918/got-a-mac-prevent-opsec-leakage-by-cleaning-hidden-os-x-files-from-usb-drives.html) The recommended freeware from that report [CleanMyDrive](http://macpaw.com/cleanmydrive) claims to be able to handle network volumes too [I'm just testing it myself so have no results as yet, but reviews are good on the app store]

Comment: That would be better, but is not possible in this case. The network is shared by a large amount of OSX machines. I'm asking specifically for a client-side solution to ignore the files.

Comment: judging by the number of hits you get on Google for 'disabling creation' vs 'ignoring' & an identical question on SE from a year ago with no solution, I'm guessing it can't be done that way. Looks like prevention will be better than cure.

Comment: Yup, i know there's not an easy to find solution. Hence my question here. Thanks for you efforts though.